# General exponential smoothing to linear functions of past observations

Tags: time-series, forecasting, state-space-models, exponential-smoothing

I am just trying to derive an equation in "Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing" page 36 section 3.2.

I am given the following

1. $\hat{y}_{t|t-1} = \textbf{w}'x_{t-1}$
2. $\epsilon_{t} = y_t - \hat{y}_{t|t-1}$
3. $\textbf{x}_t = \textbf{F}x_{t-1} + \textbf{g}\epsilon_t$

To get linear functions of past observations the book states that equations 1 and 2 are substituted into 3. to get the following

4. $x_t = \textbf{D}x_{t-1} + \textbf{g}y_t$

Where $\textbf{D} = \textbf{F} - \textbf{gw}'$

The book then states "Then back-solve the recurrence relationship" in 4 to get

5. $x_t = \textbf{D}^tx_{0} + \Sigma_{j=0}^{t-1} \textbf{D}^j\textbf{g}y_{t-j}$

Can someone proved some steps to solve 4 and 5?

I attempted some substitution, but struggled to get 4.

For 5, I am not sure what it means to "back-solve a recurrence relationship".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting (4), first substitute (2), then (1):
$$x_t=Fx_{t-1}+g(y_t-\hat y_{t|t-1})=Fx_{t-1}+gy_t-g(w'x_{t-1})=(F-gw')x_{t-1}+gy_t$$

For (5):
$$\begin{align}x_t&=Dx_{t-1}+gy_t\\&=D(Dx_{t-2}+gy_{t-1})+gy_t\\&=D^2x_{t-2}+(Dgy_{t-1}+gy_t)\\&=D^2(Dx_{t-3}+gy_{t-2})+(Dgy_{t-1}+gy_t)\\&=D^3x_{t-3}+(D^2gy_{t-2}+Dgy_{t-1}+gy_t)\\&=D^3x_{t-3}+\sum_{j=0}^2 D^jgy_{t-j}\\&=\cdots\end{align}$$

The proof can be formalized with inductive arguments but at least it should be more clear how the equation is evolving.